# How get NetworkName?

Tags: android

I can't get name when i connect internet by 3G: `active_network =null`

How get NetworkName for all Network ?

My code:

```
public String get_networkName() {
        String network_type = "";// maybe usb reverse tethering
        NetworkInfo active_network = ((ConnectivityManager) con
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE))
                .getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (active_network != null && active_network.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            if (active_network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                network_type = "WIFI";
            } else if (active_network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                network_type = "MOBILE";
            }
        }
        return network_type;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
public String get_networkName() {
    String network_type = "";// maybe usb reverse tethering
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (connec != null) {

         android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);        
         android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (wifi.isConnected()) {
            network_type = "WIFI";
        } else if (mobile.isConnected()) {
            network_type = "MOBILE";
        }
    }
    return network_type;
}
```

Comment: @mum may be your context is null check that